# unit root test for unbalanced panel data

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I want to conduct unit root test for my unbalanced multi-variate panel data.
I use only R studio. I saw many helpful posts on Stata and EViews but I am seeking solutions for RStudio only, please.
I searched on the internet how to conduct the test but I haven't been able to find a successful solution.

I saw that for `purtest(..., test="hadri")` (of package `plm`) and others are not suitable for unbalanced panel data.
In one of the posts, I saw that the Fisher-type test is applicable to the unbalanced test but I'm not sure how to write codes for the Fisher-type unit root test.
I also saw posts on how to balance panel data from unbalanced ones to carry out tests but in my case, I don't think that's what I need.

Any code examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at the example given in `?purtest`.

Comment: If @Helix123 answer doesn't solve your issue you can also try posting on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The help for function `purtest` of package `plm` lists the Fisher-style tests (there is no one such test but several) and gives an example how the test is performed:

> Several Fisher-type tests that combine p-values from tests based on
> ADF regressions per individual are available:
>
> "madwu" is the inverse chi-squared test Maddala and Wu (1999), also
> called P test by Choi (2001).
>
> "Pm" is the modified P test proposed by Choi (2001) for large N,
>
> "invnormal" is the inverse normal test by Choi (2001), and
>
> "logit" is the logit test by Choi (2001).

The specific test is requested by argument `test` to `purtest`, e.g. `test = "madwu"`.

Here is an example with an unbalanced data set.

```
library("plm")
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
# data Grunfeld is balanced but we make it unbalanced by dropping
# the last 5 observations in the next step when converting to a pdata.frame
pGrunfeld_unbal <- pdata.frame(Grunfeld[-c(195:200), ], index = c("firm", "year"))

purtest(pGrunfeld_unbal$inv, pmax = 4, exo = "intercept", test = "madwu")

##  Maddala-Wu Unit-Root Test (ex. var.: Individual Intercepts)
##
##  data:  pGrunfeld_unbal$inv
##  chisq = 18.384, df = 20, p-value = 0.5621
##  alternative hypothesis: stationarity
```